# MySQL COUNT rows in two separate JOINs gives wrong result

Tags: mysql, sql

I am attempting to join two tables to my query and count the number of matching rows from each of the joins.  It seems to come back with the wrong result though.  It seems to be doubling the results.  Here is the query

```
SELECT *, COUNT(car_id) AS numCars, COUNT(van_id) AS numVans 
            FROM company_branch
            LEFT JOIN car ON car_branchid = company_branch_id
            LEFT JOIN van ON van_branchid = company_branch_id
            WHERE company_branch_userid = 1

            GROUP BY company_branch_id, 
            ORDER BY company_branch_active DESC, company_branch_name ASC
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming that `car_id` is the primary key on the `car` table and `van_id` is the primary key on the `van` table. In that case, use `DISTINCT` to get the counts in each group individually. Try this:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(DISTINCT car_id) AS numCars, COUNT(DISTINCT van_id) AS numVans 
        FROM company_branch
        LEFT JOIN car ON car_branchid = company_branch_id
        LEFT JOIN van ON van_branchid = company_branch_id
        WHERE company_branch_userid = 1

        GROUP BY company_branch_id, 
        ORDER BY company_branch_active DESC, company_branch_name ASC
```

Comment: For me worked also, also thank you for explanation also. Now I am smarter thanks to you